# Enemy Follow Player Orthogonal Movement

Tags: xna, c#, monogame

I have a Enemy class that Seeks a player if he is in his field of view.
Problem is i want the enemy only to move up/down/right/left, not like for example up and left at the same time (diagonal movement).

**EDIT**: **Code updated**

```
    private void SeekPlayer(GameTime gameTime, Player player)
    {
        directionToPlayer = player.Image.Position - Image.Position;
        directionToPlayer.Normalize();

        if(Image.Position != player.Image.Position)
        {
            if (directionToPlayer.X != player.Image.Position.X)
            {
                if(directionToPlayer.X < player.Image.Position.X)
                    Image.Position.X += directionToPlayer.X * MoveSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                else
                    Image.Position.X -= directionToPlayer.X * MoveSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            }
            else if (directionToPlayer.Y != player.Image.Position.Y)
            {
                if (directionToPlayer.Y < player.Image.Position.Y)
                    Image.Position.Y += directionToPlayer.Y * MoveSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                else
                    Image.Position.Y -= directionToPlayer.Y * MoveSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            }

        }
        UpdateFOV();
    }
```

With the current code the enemy sometimes follows the play on the X coordinates, and when it's the same has the player's, doesn't continue to follow on the Y coordinate. And vice-versa for Y.

[image: Gameplay]

Comment: Do you want to be moved on X or Y first ?

Comment: I want `X` first

Comment: What is your question?  Looks like it's doing exactly what you've specified that you want it to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some serious issues. First of all, in games, you generally don't want to be moving objects on the screen by a flat amount per frame, because then the frame rate can make you go faster or slower, which is not a good thing. The way you want to be moving your objects is with delta time, which is the elapsed time between this and the previous Update() call.

As far as 'moving to target location' goes, you will need something better than a magical hard-coded number `0.1f`. Check out [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98333/help-on-transition-from-one-position-to-another/98334#98334) question, on how to move an object from one point to another, in XNA/Monogame.

Looking at your code, I don't see any reason for your `directionToPlayer` and `Velocity` variables to not be declared inside your `SeekPlayer()` function, so I declared them there. Also, you have the exact same code in an `if-else` statement. There is no point on doing that, since it is going to get called either way. So you might as well call it after the `if-else` statement. And finally, there is no point in using `return;` as the final command of a `void` function. It is going to return anyway.

```
float speed = 2;
Vector2 velocity = player.Image.Position - Image.Position;
velocity.Normalize();

if(velocity.X > 0.1f) // still not close enough on X-axis
    Image.Position.X += speed; // move on X-axis
else if(velocity.Y > 0.1f) // still not close enough on Y-axis
    Image.Position.Y += speed;  // move on Y-axis
UpdateFOV();
```

Comment: The `Velocity`variable is not declared inside the `SeekPlayer()`because the enemy will move (wander) if the player is not im his FOV.
So i **updated my code**, and now the problem is that enemy.X is never equals no player.X. It goes to the infite.. 0,000(0)1... Making the enemy following the player on the X axis

Comment: Why multiply with the velocity?
That will move the enemy on the axes with different speed, in relation to the angle to the player. It should be

    `Image.Position.X|Y += speed * deltaTime;`

Comment: @xRed Of course the `enemy.X` won't be equal to `player.X` (most of the time). Lets say you have values `player.X = 500` and `enemy.X = 300` and you increase the `enemy.X` by `3` every frame. Who guarantees you that it will reach exactly the value `500` ? In this specific case it won't. This is one of the reasons why your code as a whole is bad. You can check the question I linked in my question for a completely different approach.

Comment: @Shiro That will still result in different velocities for X/Y most of the time.
If you normalize (3|1), than you will get X=3/sqrt(10) and Y=1/sqrt(10).

Comment: @user000user Oh yes, my bad, you are correct. It was presented like this in the original question and I didn't realize this could happen.

Comment: The link you provided will result in what i had before, wich is the enemy moving diagonaly (a bit X, and a bit Y almost at same time).

Comment: @xRed I mean... the answer is right in front of you. It requires  the smallest effort to modify it.